# System unresponsive if left unattended for a few days

Tags: 14.04

I have a consistent problem with my Ubuntu 14LTS system. If I leave my system unattended for say 3-4 days it freezes. The display is On showing the last used screen but it doesn't respond to mouse/keyboard events. Ping from a different machine also does not return anything.

I have tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 from other pointers over the internet but the System doesn't respond to that; probably due to all keyboard events are ignored as well.

The only option is to hard-reboot the system by holding the system power button for a few seconds.

I would like to debug this problem. Please let me know if I need to post any specific logs, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Usually a system locks up when we do something. It's not often it locks up when we do nothing. On new Intel Bay Trail CPU's with Kernel version < 4.7.2 there are reports of freezing unless "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" is on the grub command line.

Your first choices after reboot are to look at dmesg. Then look at /var/log/kern.log (go to the end and scroll up). Then look at /var/log/syslog (also starting at end). Hopefully error messages are listed indicating what is leading up to the freeze up. Some users have a /var/log/messages file that can be viewed but it doesn't exist on my system (Ubuntu 16.04 / Kernel 4.7.2).

Because you are doing nothing for 3 or 4 days yet the system crashes on it's own my inclination is it's running out of memory (RAM + SWAP). To confirm this you will have to check on it once a day and type:

```
free -t
```

in the terminal. If my hunch is right each day you will see less and less available memory until the third or fourth day when there is none left. If my hunch is wrong there are no warranties on the crystal ball and you are back at square one digging though message files.

What applications are running on your system whilst unattended for 3 or 4 days? A poorly written application can allocate RAM for working storage and then forget to give it back to the Operating System later.

Comment: Reputation: 404 >>> ERROR: "Reputation" returned 404. (i.e. I +1'd your answer, it's a good one)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος - 404 error - I don't exist...haha - thanks for compliment!

Comment: I didn't realize I had gotten an answer already. Apparently I don't get emailed when somebody posts an answer to my question. I will try the free -t solution and see how that goes. I have Jira installed on my system; I recently noticed that my database has gone bad for Jira. May be the memory issue is due to Jira going crazy. I will post free -t results soon.

Comment: @user3761169 Just curious if you've had a chance to try `free -t` to monitor your memory usage.